# Does elasticsearch support searching and reporting on serialized java.time.Instant fields?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-data, couchbase

I have the following json :

```
Order {

   "creationDate" : 1441108800000,
   "expiryDate" : 253402300799000

}
```

While creating java objects I use Instant (e.g Instant.now() to set the creation date) to set the dates for creation and expiry. When I serialize this into the couchbase DB using spring data and jackson dependencies I get the above json. These documents are replicated to elastic for searching purposes.

Is elastic able to search for these type of dates? e.g. the search could be for expired orders? Can it handle date conversions etc?

If this is not the best way to store datetime please suggest a better approach to handle date-time requirements in general considering timezones, spring couchbase serialization and searching using elastic search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what works for me :

I am storing dates as longs I found it easier to compare and do the maths on it only while showing in UI I convert it to a human readable form as per the timezone. We can get it in java by calling instant.toEpochMilli(). Spring data has not problem in serializing and deserializing it and elastic search has a Date datatype which we can set up while defining the mapping for our document.

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to use the date/time manipulation functions of the N1QL query language in Couchbase, I suggest you use human-readable date/time-stamps, like `2006-01-02T15:04:05.999+00:00`. They are what works best with these functions. And this format is widely supported in other contexts, too.

More here:
https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/datefun.html